# Why can't see account(DBA) 's activities in SYS.AUD$?

Tags: oracle

I have set `audit_sys_operations` to true, `audit_trail` is DB,EXTENDED.  now I have a account name `admin` who have DBA privilige. I use `AUDIT CREATE ANY TABLE BY ADMIN`, But the  `select * from SYS.AUD$` just show nothing about admin creating a new table even when admin did create several tables;

can I see the audit record of user with DBA privilege ?

Comment: Sys audit trails are stored in filesystem. Documentation link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG94425

Comment: @JSapkota it seems that since I set the audit_trail to DB,Extended, it will not log SYSDBA trail as XML. I check the the `.aud` file, I don't understand its meaning..

Comment: For xml you can set AUDIT_TRAIL initialization parameter to XML or XML, EXTENDED.

Comment: Thank you JSapkota, I just not sure whether the XML will make more sense if it just change from `DBID:[10] ` to something like <DBID>10</DBID>

Comment: ok..previously I check the orcl_pmon_xxxxxxxx file, I found that `orcl_ora_xxxx_xxxxxxxxx` make much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to audit what SYS does, you'll need to set the AUDIT_SYS_OPERATIONS parameter to TRUE which you already did. But SYS operations won't be written to SYS.AUD$ for security reasons. Since SYS can delete rows from the AUD$ table, the SYS audit trail has to be written to the file system (where, presumably, you can configure file permissions so that the DBA cannot modify the audit trail).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I will make a summary here for future come-acrossers.

> **AUDIT_TRAIL**=DB/TRUE enables systemwide auditing where audited records are written to the
>       database audit trail(the **SYS.AUD$** table). The only audit data that will not be written to the table is the audit data pertaining to the activities of SYSDBA.

As I had set AUDI_TRAIL， I can see audited activities in **SYS.AUD$**。

As stated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-58176267-238C-40B5-B1F2-BB8BB9518950.htm):

> **AUDIT_SYS_OPERATIONS** enables or disables the auditing of top-level operations, which are SQL statements directly issued by users when connecting with the **SYSASM**, **SYSBACKUP**, **SYSDBA**, **SYSDG**, **SYSKM**, or **SYSOPER** privileges. (SQL statements run from within PL/SQL procedures or functions are not considered top-level.) The audit records are written to the operating system's audit trail. The audit records will be written in XML format if the AUDIT_TRAIL initialization parameter is set to xml or xml, extended.

Since I had set `audit_sys_operations` to `true`, oracle will audit `SYSDBA` activities, but the records will not show up in **SYS.AUD$** , it will be at (in my case `/u01/app/oracle/admin/orcl/adump`) .

But be careful, do not look up the wrong audit log file. The activities record are contained in file like `orcl_ora_6225_20160513082219532252143795.aud`
. I share some of it's contents below:

```
ACTION :[14] 'drop table foo'
DATABASE USER:[1] '/'
PRIVILEGE :[6] 'SYSDBA'
CLIENT USER:[6] 'oracle'
CLIENT TERMINAL:[5] 'pts/3'
STATUS:[3] '942'
DBID:[10] '1439309578'

Fri May 13 08:00:17 2016 -07:00
LENGTH : '205'
ACTION :[51] 'CREATE TABLE FOO(
        FOO1 INTEGER,
        BAR VARCHAR(10)
)'
DATABASE USER:[1] '/'
PRIVILEGE :[6] 'SYSDBA'
CLIENT USER:[6] 'oracle'
CLIENT TERMINAL:[5] 'pts/3'
STATUS:[1] '0'
DBID:[10] '1439309578'
```

You can see that I used an account with SYSDBA privilige to drop a table named foo and recreate it. The number in the brackets is the length of the value.

That's how auditing SYSDBA works.